# windows server 2003 R2 64bit not seeing more than 4gb ram

Tags: windows-server-2003, memory

shouldn't win 2003 R2 64bit see more than 4gb by default or am I missing a setting somewhere? hardware is SuperMicro X6DVA-EG.

http://msdn.mzicrosoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2003

Comment: That's odd, if it's visible in BIOS and POST, it should work. Can you post a screenshot of taskman with the memory tab? Which version of Windows 2003 are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventhough it was a windows 2003 64bit, I ended up adding PAE(physical address extension) to boot for it to see more than 4gb ram.

c:>bootcfg /id 1 /raw PAE

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Does the BIOS see it?  The supermicro's can be really funny with RAM placement..

Comment: Yes. I can see 8gb in bios and POST.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the RAM is installed according to the [Manual](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/E7320/MNL-0746.pdf)

> an interleaved memory scheme is used,
>   you must install two modules at a
>   time, beginning with DIMM #1A, then
>   DIMM #1B, and so on